# Barcode or 2D-Code scanner for Android, capable of scanning from displays

Tags: android, scanner, barcode-scanner

We’re implementing an access control system where people bring a code, printed or on a smartphone (their choice), to get access.

We are free in the choice of code system, as long as it’s capable of encoding a 14-digit alpha-numeric string. QR works, as well as Code128.

We want to allow scanning with off-the-shelf Android devices. Our first idea was to use a barcode scanning app, but the autofocus of the camera is too slow and each scan takes around 10 - 20 seconds. Sometimes, e.g. on a sunny day, the camera-based scanner would not even work at all.

What we’re looking for now is an external scanner with the following features:

- Runs with Android.
- Connects via Bluetooth (prefered) or USB.
- Able to read from a smartphone screen or paper, even under non-ideal conditions.
- Easy configuration and usage for less tech-savvy users.
- Ideally some kind of targeting assistance, e.g. a red dot/line/cross.
- Ideally 100 Euros or less; hopefully not more than 200.

I have found several cheap laser scanners on Amazon and ordered one of them. It is pretty solid and works nicely with paper, but I didn’t know that this type of scanner cannot scan from smartphone displays.

Comment: Bit off topic, but I just wanted to let you know that the link to Tixys on your profile seems to be dead.

Comment: @JMY1000: Thanks for the notice, but I just tried the links on my SE/SO/Network profiles, and they seem to be ok. Do you remember an error message? Or did the request time out? Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be good now! It wasn't able to resolve the domain name.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe some network hiccup at my hosting ISP.